# Symplectic forms on $\mathbb{C}P^3$ with trivial first Chern class

Tags: symplectic-geometry, almost-complex

### Question

Does there exist a symplectic form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{C}P^3$
with first Chern class $c_1(\mathbb{C} P^3, \omega) = 0$?

### Context

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold.
An almost complex structure $J$ on $M$ is *compatible* with $\omega$
if the bilinear form $(u,v) \mapsto \omega(u, Jv)$ is an inner product.
The space of compatible structures is non-empty and contractible.
This allows us to define the Chern classes $c_k(M,\omega)$
as $c_k(TM, J)$, where $J$ is any compatible almost complex structure on $M$.

It is well known that the Fubini-Study form $\omega_{\operatorname{FS}}$
on $\mathbb{C} P^3$ is compatible with the standard complex structure,
making $\mathbb{C} P^3$ into a Kähler manifold (and more generally the
same is true for $\mathbb{C}P^n$).
Note that in this case we have
$c_1(\mathbb{C}P^3, \omega_{\operatorname{FS}}) = \pm 4 x$,
where
$x \in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^3; \mathbb{Z})$
is a generator.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{C} P^3$ has many almost complex structures
that are not isomorphic to the standard one.
For example, one finds the following result in [1] (see Theorem 3.2 therein).

> For every $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is an almost complex structure $J$
> on $\mathbb{C} P^3$ with $c_1(\mathbb{C} P^3, J) = 2 q x$, where
> $x \in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^3; \mathbb{Z})$
> is a choice of generator.

The above claim can be proved using obstruction theory.
On the other hand, I do not know of an explicit
construction of the non-standard almost complex structures.

This leads to the question: are any of the non-standard almost complex structures on
$\mathbb{C}P^3$ compatible with a symplectic form?
The question stated above is concerned with the special case $c_1 = 0$.

---

[1] Thomas, E.
Complex structures on real vector bundles.
Amer. J. Math.89(1967), 887–908.
[MR0220310](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=220310)

Comment: This is an open question. A good paper to learn about the state of the art for existence and uniqueness of symplectic forms is this one by Salamon. https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/unique.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference. My naive guess was that there might be some algebraic-topological reason why such symplectic forms would not exist, but this was too optimistic...